# Curve geom_line() with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `ggplot()` and `geom-line()` as follows

```
ggplot(tabla3) + geom_line(aes(tabla3$MC, tabla3$Normal), lwd = 1)
```

Result:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try `geom_bezier` in `ggforce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the mean and standard deviation of your data, why not just plot a normal distribution?

```
x <- seq(50, 90, length=101)
hx <- dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))

plot(x, hx, type = 'l')
```

ggplot version

```
ggplot(data = tibble(x), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))) + ylab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```